# How to make my application as SSO application using Shibboleth

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, shibboleth

I have written two applications one is taking user name password from user and second one is for showing some data to the user. Both are simple web applications, now my question is,

How I can make first application as IDP and second one as Service Provider ?
How can I integrate with these two with Shibboleth ?
How can I write SAML ?

please help anyone, it would great help to me...Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is just a bit too broad to solve on Stackoverflow. I advise you to Google for some tutorials. The Shibboleth documentation is notoriously bad however, so good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

Check this below tutorials, it will help you.

http://soasecurity.org/2012/05/29/configure-shibboleth-as-saml2-idp/
http://soasecurity.org/2014/12/04/federatation-shibboleth/

Best of luck!!!